# Port Number In Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, server, port, node-modules

I am learning how to create servers in Node.js using the `http` module. Although I am struggling to understand how to figure out what port number I need to use. How am I supposed to find my port number or can I just use any number? Is it different across all devices? Is there a list I can choose from?

I am very confused about this topic can someone please explain?

Comment: [See guide](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You can essentially pick to listen on whatever port you wish, provided that:

1. No other process is already listening on it
2. Ports 0-1023 are "restricted ports". On a unix-based operating system you'll need superuser privileges to bind them, on other operating systems it's just considered a bad practice.

Node.js applications often listen on port 3000 or 4000, but those are just conventions, and you don't have to follow them.